# Every linux distribution freezed "to death"

Tags: linux, freeze, crash

Trying to install linux on my home pc, already tried: PopOS, Ubuntu, Debian, Arch, Manjaro. Every distrib just freezes without any response after ~1-15minutes. Somehow managed to install debian with gnome and get some logs.
Asking for help here, because i've run out of options, after searching everything that i can google, managed to get debian work for 10 minutes with X.M.P profile on(it was disabled by default).
Can someone please help me understand what causes this error?
My specs:

- Gigabyte B450M Gaming X
- Ryzen 5 3500x
- Nvidia Geforce 1650
- 2x8GB DDR4 2666GHz AMD ram

Trying to install on Silicon Power 128GB SSD
Here's some logs that i got in debian before freeze:

```
May 31 20:16:09 CandyDeb gnome-shell[1279]: Couldn't find child [0x564738d5f170 Gjs_ui_windowPreview_WindowPreview ("Software")] in window slots
May 31 20:16:09 CandyDeb gnome-shell[1279]: Couldn't find child [0x564738d5f170 Gjs_ui_windowPreview_WindowPreview ("Software")] in window slots
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915657] BUG: Bad page state in process Web Content  pfn:192eac
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915662] page:000000009b7abecc refcount:0 mapcount:0 mapping:0000000000000000 index:0x1 pfn:0x192eac
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915663] flags: 0xb(locked|referenced|dirty)
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915665] raw: 000000000000000b dead000000000100 dead000000000122 0000000000000000
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915665] raw: 0000000000000001 0000000000000000 00000000ffffffff 0000000000000000
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915666] page dumped because: PAGE_FLAGS_CHECK_AT_PREP flag(s) set
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915666] Modules linked in: exfat rfkill edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi nls_ascii kvm nls_cp437 snd_hda_intel irqbypass snd_intel_dspcfg vfat soundwire_intel ghash_clmulni_intel fat soundwire_generic_allocation snd_soc_core snd_compress soundwire_cadence snd_hda_codec aesni_intel snd_hda_core libaes crypto_simd snd_hwdep cryptd soundwire_bus glue_helper snd_pcm rapl snd_timer sp5100_tco snd joydev wmi_bmof efi_pstore pcspkr k10temp watchdog ccp soundcore sg tpm_crb tpm_tis tpm_tis_core tpm rng_core evdev acpi_cpufreq msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport fuse configfs efivarfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 crc32c_generic uas usb_storage hid_generic usbhid hid nouveau mxm_wmi video i2c_algo_bit sd_mod ttm xhci_pci drm_kms_helper xhci_hcd ahci libahci cec crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel drm i2c_piix4 libata usbcore r8169 nvme usb_common realtek scsi_mod mdio_devres nvme_core libphy t10_pi crc_t10dif crct10dif_generic
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915704]  crct10dif_pclmul crct10dif_common wmi gpio_amdpt gpio_generic button
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915707] CPU: 4 PID: 3134 Comm: Web Content Not tainted 5.10.0-14-amd64 #1 Debian 5.10.113-1
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915708] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. B450 GAMING X/B450 GAMING X, BIOS F63b 05/11/2022
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915709] Call Trace:
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915715]  dump_stack+0x6b/0x83
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915716]  bad_page.cold+0x63/0x94
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915718]  get_page_from_freelist+0x91c/0x1320
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915720]  __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x161/0x310
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915722]  alloc_pages_vma+0x80/0x260
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915724]  handle_mm_fault+0xe69/0x1bf0
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915727]  do_user_addr_fault+0x1b8/0x3f0
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915729]  exc_page_fault+0x78/0x160
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915731]  ? asm_exc_page_fault+0x8/0x30
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915731]  asm_exc_page_fault+0x1e/0x30
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915733] RIP: 0033:0x3f790f087881
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915734] Code: 4a 04 48 8d 4a 08 8b 70 04 33 db f7 00 10 00 00 00 48 0f 44 c3 48 8d 58 08 f7 00 40 00 00 00 48 0f 44 58 08 48 8b c3 0f b6 18 <88> 19 48 83 c0 01 48 83 c1 01 83 ee 01 75 ee 8b 77 04 33 db f7 07
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915735] RSP: 002b:00007ffe7edce9f8 EFLAGS: 00010202
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915736] RAX: 00003922abd6efe0 RBX: 0000000000000035 RCX: 00003922abd6f000
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915736] RDX: 00003922abd6eff8 RSI: 0000000000000003 RDI: 00002f5313485ca0
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915736] RBP: 00003922abd6ee80 R08: 00003922abd6efd8 R09: 00007ffe7edcea88
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915737] R10: 00007ffe7edce9e0 R11: 00007eff82f1c902 R12: 0000000000000008
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915737] R13: 00007eff82f06098 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
May 31 20:16:14 CandyDeb kernel: [  380.915739] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
```

Debian info from syslog:

```
Linux version 5.10.0-14-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc-10 (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.35.2) #1 SMP Debian 5.10.113-1 (2022-04-29)
```

Photo from pure arch install: [image]

Comment: What version of Debian are you running, downloaded from where? What's the proprietary kernel module you've installed ("Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint")?

Comment: Official debian 11 from debian.org. Standard install.
`Linux version 5.10.0-14-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc-10 (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.35.2) #1 SMP Debian 5.10.113-1 (2022-04-29)`
Line from same syslog

Comment: Could be down to the nouveau driver. Please install proprietary NVIDIA drivers instead. Debian 10 is way too old for your PC and generally debian is **not** a distro for modern PCs. It's more a server-grade distro.

Comment: I got same "freeze" on manjaro with open-source and with proprietary install.
Oh wait.. it's debian 10.. Ok then. I have a photo of arch crash, let me upload it, but i don't think that it's informative

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/aEIVQ4c here, it's from arch. This is from when i tried to install pure arch from scratch
looks similar..
Can it be bios config problem? My bios has way to much options for me to understand where this is happening...

Comment: Thank you @ScitiTheCandyborn. Please add the new information into your question, so it's easy for people to find. Comments are often ignored by people who've not contributed to them so it's a poor place to leave important information. Thanks

Comment: 1. Check your RAM using memtest86 2. Update BIOS to the latest version. 3. Reset BIOS settings

Comment: Did this all already. No errors on memtest. Also tried with just one stick of ram in different slots and two sticks on single\dual channel

Comment: Can you please help me understand what this error says? Is this something about it can't read info from specific ram sector?